# Yet another tf problem

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Doing this :

```
print self.tf_listener.lookupTransform("/map", "/camera_frame", rospy.Time(0))
pose_camera_frame.header.stamp = rospy.Time(0)
pose_world_frame = self.tf_transformer.transformPose("/map", pose_camera_frame)
```

The first line works and I get the transform between /map and /camera_frame. But when I want to transform my pose which is defined in camera_frame to the map frame, I get this error:

```
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 711, in _invoke_callback
    cb(msg)   File "/opt/workspaces/catkin_ws/src/sp_navigation/scripts/sp_sub.py", line 515, in callback
    pose_world_frame = self.tf_transformer.transformPose("/map", pose_camera_frame)   File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf/listener.py", line 188, in transformPose
    mat44 = self.asMatrix(target_frame, ps.header) File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf/listener.py", line 75, in asMatrix
    translation,rotation = self.lookupTransform(target_frame, hdr.frame_id, hdr.stamp) LookupException: "map" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist.
```

But tf just saw that map existed and had no problem giving me the transform between map and camera_frame.
pose_camera_frame is a PoseStamped variable with

```
pose_camera_frame.header.frame_id = "camera_frame"
```

And tf listener and transformer are defined as follows:

```
# Create a TF listener
self.tf_listener = tf.TransformListener()
# Create a TF transformer
self.tf_transformer = tf.TransformerROS()
```

Why does this happen?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215528/yet-another-tf-problem/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2015-08-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Okay I just discovered that TransformListener class also has the ability to transform a given pose from one frame to another. Using:

```
pose_world_frame = self.tf_listener.transformPose("/map", pose_camera_frame)
```

works somehow. But I would be still interested to know why TransformerROS doesn't work. Was it implemented at an abstract level where it is called by higher level functions?

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2015-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1